# It does print output but why it is not writing in file?

Tags: python, subprocess

```
import subprocess
f = open("sum.txt","a")
def execute(cmd):
        popen = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
        for stdout_line in iter(popen.stdout.readline, ""):
            yield stdout_line 
        popen.stdout.close()
        return_code = popen.wait()
        if return_code:
            raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(return_code, cmd)




for uses in execute(['ls','-ltr']):
    f.write(uses)
    print(uses)
```

Comment: You should `close` the file after you're done with it

Comment: Did you close the file?

Comment: after closing file instead of listing files it gives me  total number and writes total in file

Comment: @SumitDuwal, can you show your updated code and ouput?

Comment: total 36

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

Comment: @SumitDuwal, did you by any chance close the file inside the `for` loop? Can you update your code in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the context-manager to open a file. With this solution your file will be closed.

**Code:**

```
import subprocess


def execute(cmd):
        popen = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
        for stdout_line in iter(popen.stdout.readline, ""):
            yield stdout_line
        popen.stdout.close()
        return_code = popen.wait()
        if return_code:
            raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(return_code, cmd)


with open("sum.txt", "a") as opened_file:
    for uses in execute(['ls', '-ltr']):
        opened_file.write(uses)
        print(uses)
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python3 test.py 
total 96

-rw-rw-r-- 1 milanbalazs users  637 Jul 29 12:30 README.md

drwxrwxr-x 4 milanbalazs users 4096 Jul 29 12:30 admin

-rwxrwxr-x 1 milanbalazs users 1706 Jul 29 12:30 bash_unit_test.sh
```

The content of sum.txt file is same.

Answer (score 1):

You need to close the file after writing to it after the `for` loop has completed

```py
for uses in execute(['ls','-ltr']):
    f.write(uses)

f.close()
```

This is safer in a  `try`... `finally` block as it will close the file even if there is an error when performing operations on the file.

```py
try:
    f = open("sum.txt","a")
    for uses in execute(['ls','-ltr']):
        f.write(uses)
finally:
    f.close()
```

Or better yet, using the `with` statement as this will close the file once the statement has executed

```py
with open("sum.txt","a") as f:
    for uses in execute(['ls','-ltr']):
        f.write(uses)
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid these type of errors, use `with open()` in code. It will automatically close the file.